# ошибка Thread1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: xcode, swift3, firebase

Пишу код на Swift 3 в Xcode 8. Создаю пользовательский аккаунт с помощью Firebase, но при запуске программы появляется ошибка: **"Thread1: signal SIGABRT"**, указывающая на строку `class AppDelegate`.

Описание ошибки:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Storage bucket cannot be initialized with a path'
```

С чем может быть связано появление данной ошибки?

Все кнопки привязаны правильно, контроллеры имеют нужный класс.
Проблема возникает при работе именно с FireBaseStorage, с FirebaseDatabase, например, проблем нет.

Answer (score 1):

как пишут [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485769/ios-swift-firebase-storage-error-no-default-storage-bucket-found/43486410) надо инициализировать Firebase Storage перед обращением:

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
```

а вообще, нужно добавить Exception Breakpoint, и тогда (возможно) при падении будет указываться именно проблемное место в программе, а не AppDelegate.

Comment: Firebase Storage уже инициализирован. C Breakpoint попробую, спасибо